# Import from dependency not found when script runs via gradle task

Tags: java, gradle

I have a gradle task that executes a java class:

```java
task generateKyFunctions {
  doLast {
    javaexec {
      main = 'come.example.MyClass'
      classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    }
  }

  dependsOn("build")
  finalizedBy("prettify")
}
```

My class imports files from another package:

```java
import cz.habarta.typescript.generator.Input;
import cz.habarta.typescript.generator.Input.Parameters;
import cz.habarta.typescript.generator.TypeScriptGenerator;
```

Yet when the gradle task runs, it errors:

`error: package cz.habarta.typescript.generator does not exist`

I have the lib declared in my dependencies block:

`developmentOnly 'cz.habarta.typescript-generator:typescript-generator:3.2.1263'`

So I'm not sure what I've missed.